# Write a program that keeps reading positive numbers from the user until the user entered negative numbers

Tags: python

> Write a program that keeps reading positive numbers from the user. The program should only quit when the user enters a negative value. Once the user enters a negative value the program should print the average of all the numbers entered.

Here is my code so far

```
def main():
    number = 1
    numbers = []
    while (number > 0):
        number = int(input("Enter a number, put in a negative number to end: "))
        if number > 0 :
            numbers.append(number)
    ratarata = len(numbers)
    print ("Average number entered: ", ratarata)
main()
```

This is the output:

[image: screenshot of output]

Comment: What is your problem ? BTW you should add all entered values and then divide by the number of valid (positive) entry.

Comment: You could use [`statistics.mean()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) to calculate the average value of the `numbers`.

Comment: The output shown is **not** the output your program produces.

Comment: This question sounds like a homework assignment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than having an item counter and a running total, use a list as follows:

```
list_ = list()
while (n := int(input("Enter a number, put in a negative number to end: "))) >= 0:
    list_.append(n)
print('Average number entered: ', sum(list_) / len(list_) if list_ else 0)
```

**Note:**

This will fail if the input cannot be converted to int

Answer (score 0):

```
sum_num=0
count=0
while True:
    val=int(input())
    if val>=0:
       sum_num+=val
       count+=1
    else:
      break 
try:
   print(sum_num/count)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print(0)
```

ZeroDivisionError will come when your first input in not positive number
while True: is infinite loop which will take infinite input until condition are true.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working answer

```py
number=1
numbers=[]
while number>0:
    number=float(input("Enter a positive number. (or a negative number to quit)"))
    if number>0:
        numbers.append(number)
print("The sum of your numbers is", sum(numbers))
print("The average is", (sum(numbers)/len(numbers)))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).